# How to improve hyponasal sound?

Tags: voice

Sometimes I feel that my voice sounds as if my nostrils are blocked, and I am catching a cold. (I listen to my speaking recorded by my laptop.) It will sound better, if I pay more attention to pronounce nasal sounds. But I don't know how to consciously do that.

This is what I understand "hyponasal" intended to mean. (I haven't been able to find a recording sample of hyponasal voice on the internet yet.)

Do you have ways to improve it? I especially like to know non-surgery or non-medical way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Practice speaking and singing with exaggerated and very animated motions - read yourself a book out loud as if you are telling a story to a small child.  Open your mouth wide, exaggerate your facial expressions, try and pronounce things as well as you can.  Many people who sing don't take care of their speaking voice and it leads to a dull sound.